# How do you use layout.adoptLayout(layout) in PySide?

Tags: python, pyside2, qlayout

I have

```
widget = QtWidgets.Widgets()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(parent=widget)
```

Now in certain situations I want to change the `QVBoxLayout` to a `QHBoxLayout`, and I want to do this after creation if possible. That is, without simply creating a `QHBoxLayout` from the get go.

I have tried using

```
layout.adoptLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
```

But this simply returns `True`, and doesn't change the actual layout.

Comment: I just want layout to change from vertical to horizontal. Currently nothing is happening. I feel like I did get this working at one point, but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: Note: adoptLayout is an internal method that should not be exposed so I think it is a bug since it is also not documented.

Comment: You can find adoptLayout within QLayout:
https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QLayout.html?highlight=addchildwidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QLayout.adoptLayout

Comment: There it only says the type of input and the type of output but it does not say that it does that function.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's a dead-end then. :/

Comment: But I think that for your underlying problem there may be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** `adoptLayout/(` is an internal method that should not be exposed so I think it is a bug since it is also not documented.

To implement the change of direction then you can use the QBoxLayout class:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    lay = QtWidgets.QBoxLayout(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom, widget)

    for i in range(4):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"button {i}")
        lay.addWidget(button)

    widget.show()

    def on_timeout():
        direction = (
            QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom
            if lay.direction() == QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight
            else QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight
        )
        lay.setDirection(direction)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: setDirection does the trick. Thanks for the solution!